# Swift 2: Alamofire GET Issue

Tags: swift2, xcode7, alamofire

I'm trying to perform a GET request but am getting the following two errors:

> use of unresolved identifier 'self'

and

> Expected declaration

This is my affected code

```
let credentialData = "\(self._username):\(self._password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://gemcave.pythonanywhere.com/api/order\(self._username)/\(self._password)", headers: headers)
.responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)
}
```

[image: Errors encountered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code into some method like this:

```
func networkConfiguration() {
  let credentialData = "\(self._username):\(self._password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
  let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://gemcave.pythonanywhere.com/api/order\(self._username)/\(self._password)", headers: headers)
  .responseJSON { response in
  debugPrint(response)
  }
}
```